# what's the syntax to bind reference to pointer?(all kinds)

Tags: c++, pointers, reference, constants

Here is the code:

```
int main()
{   
    int* p = nullptr;
    const int* cp = p;
    const int*& ref = cp;
    const int*& ref0 = cp;
    const int*& ref1 = p;//not allowed
    const int*& ref2 = static_cast<const int*&>(p);//not allowed
    int* const & ref3 = p;//allowed. Why?
    return 0;
}
```

When I run it, I got

```
test.cpp:7:14: error: non-const lvalue reference to type 'const int *' cannot
      bind to a value of unrelated type 'int *'
        const int*& ref1 = p;
                    ^      ~
test.cpp:8:21: error: non-const lvalue reference to type 'const int *' cannot
      bind to a value of unrelated type 'int *'
        const int*& ref2 = static_cast<const int*&>(p);
```

I am having trouble understanding why. Maybe `const` plays a role here. And when I wrote `const int*&` or `int* const &`, I don't know `const` apply to pointer or reference. And `const int* const &` confuses me too.
I want to know the syntax for the following item:

A reference to a pointer that is const.

A reference to a pointer that points to a const.

A reference to a pointer that is const and points to a const.

And const reference version:

A const reference to a pointer.

A const reference to a pointer that is const.

A const reference to a pointer that points to a const.

A const reference to a pointer that is const and points to a const.

Sorry for my confusion.

Comment: The variable called `ref` is not actually a reference, it's a pointer.

Comment: @Eljay sorry for the mistype. I corrected it already.

Comment: Because `const` is not transitive, these are two different types:  `const int*` and `int *`.  So when you bind a reference to a pointer, the type of the reference has to match the type of the referred to thing.  As per your final example, it is okay for the const pointer reference to be made to a non-const pointer.  Keep in mind that pointer is itself a value, because it appears you are thinking of a pointer as something other than a value.

Answer (score 4):

Your `p` is a pointer to an `int`. `const int*&` is a reference to a pointer to a `const` `int`. Since `p` is an `int` and not a `const` `int`, you cannot bind a reference that is supposed to refer to a pointer to a `const` `int` to refer to `p`.

The key to reading declarations in C++ is to read them "from the inside out", i.e., start from the identifier (name) and work your way out. Take your example:

```
int* const & ref3;
```

is a reference to a `const` pointer to an `int`. We start at the identifier (`ref3`) and work outwards. The first thing we find is an `&`. So `ref3` is a reference. Next thing is `const`, so whatever `ref3` refers to is a `const` something. Next thing is a `*`, so the `const` thing the reference refers to is a pointer. Finally `int`, we're dealing with a reference to a `const` pointer to an `int`.

Note that you can have stuff happening to both sides of the identifier. When "working your way out", you have to consider which specifiers/operators bind first/more strongly to figure out what type is declared. For example:

```
int const * a[10];
```

Again, we start at the identifier `a`. The `[]` binds more strongly than `*`, so `a` is an array of 10 elements. What are these elements that `a` is an array of? Next comes a `*`, so `a` is an array of 10 pointers to something. In the end, we find that `a` is an array of 10 pointers to `const` `int`. Note that if there's a lonely `const` left at the end, that `const` binds to whatever came before it. That's what allows us to also write `const int a` which is equivalent to `int const a`.

You can also use parentheses to influence the order in which operators take effect in a declaration. For example

```
int const (* a)[10];
```

would be a pointer to an array of 10 `const` `int` rather than an array of 10 pointers to `const` `int`.

Comment: Thanks! Really helped a lot. Could you kindly give me some extra implementation examples related to 1.A const reference to a pointer that is const. 2.A const reference to a pointer that points to a const.3.A const reference to a pointer that is const and points to a const. ? Thank you so much! I just want to make sure I get your point.

Comment: I will gladly add some more examples. However, all your requested examples seem to ask for references that are const. To clear that up: You can have a reference that refers to something that is const, but a reference itself cannot be const, because that would not make sense. References are not really objects themselves, they simply refer to another object. They must be bound to an existing object upon initialization and cannot be changed.