# How to interpret variable declarations with right to left rule while typedef is included?

Tags: c++, c, typedef

I am having trouble when using right to left rule to interpret variable declarations when typedef is involved.

In the C++ primer 5th edition book I saw the following code:

```
typedef char *pstring;
const pstring cstr = 0; // cstr is a constant pointer to char
const pstring *ps; // ps is a pointer to a constant pointer to char
```

If I replace the pstring with char * then it stands like this:

`const char *cstr`

So I expect cstr to be a pointer to a const char. But the comments in the book states the pointer itself is constant. My question is what's wrong with my way of thinking.

Comment: Your confusion on this is understandable and a good example of why `typedef` should not be abused this way.

Comment: Reopening.  The given dup is talking about the position of `*` as in `char *p` or `char* p`.  This question is about `const` when applied to a typedef'ed pointer.

Comment: Maybe you'll find `typedef char *pstring;` easier to read as `using pstring = char *;` ..

Comment: In addition to Artyer's answer below, it should be noted that the "left-to-right rule" is, unfortunately, not an accurate model for how declarations in C (and C++) actually work. You may want to have a look at, e.g., this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51540693/whats-the-syntax-to-bind-reference-to-pointerall-kinds/51540903#51540903

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `typedef` is not a macro. You don't just text replace it.

Read it as `cstr` is a "constant `pstring`", which is a "constant (pointer to char)". Compare this to `const char*`, which is "pointer to constant `char`".

If you were to replace the typedef it would look like this:

```
char* const cstr = 0;
char* const* ps;
```

Answer (score 1):

As can be read [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/const):

> If an array type is declared with the const type qualifier (through
>   the use of typedef), the array type is not const-qualified, but its
>   element type is

Because pstring is typedef to `char *`, `const pstring cstr` is `char * const cstr`, not `const char * cstr`.